# Distance, polygon with Sparql

Tags: sparql, geospatial, jena, geosparql

In a project, I use big data which is in sparql.

I cannot calculate the distance and I cannot find all the files (PointofInterrest) that are in a point polygon (to display all the files that are in a region, for example).

I tried with geof: distance but I got this answer:

```
      }
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openrdf.query.QueryEvaluationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Exception: task=ChunkTask{query=d6f6b503-fd98-4c2c-891c-afa517fd95e0,bopId=37,partitionId=-1,sinkId=38,altSinkId=null}, cause=java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: unknown function: http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/distance
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.sail.webapp.BigdataServlet.submitApiTask(BigdataServlet.java:294)
```

I also tried with
bif:st_distance
But I can not. Could you clarify for me please? thank you

```
            PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
            PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
            PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
            PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
            PREFIX ebucore: <http://www.ebu.ch/metadata/ontologies/ebucore/ebucore#>
            PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
            PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX geof: <http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
prefix sf: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/sf> 
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
prefix ex: <http://example.org/> 
PREFIX uom: <http://www.opengis.net/def/uom/OGC/1.0/>
            SELECT 
             (...)
              BIND (geof:distance(?lat,?lon, "48.xx"^^xsd:double, "10.xx"^^xsd:double,uom:metre) as ?xr)
            }
```

Comment: so, which API and triple store do you use? Your error trace is from Blazegraph triple store, `bif:st_distance` is for the Virtuoso triple store, and your tag here is `jena`.

Comment: also, 1) Blazegraph does **not** support GeoSPARQL and 2) `geof:distance` takes three arguments with the first two being geometries, e.g. WKT literals - but not lat and long from WGS vocabulary. In that case you have to create the WKT literal first, i.e. make a literal of form "POINT(long lat)"^^geo:wktLiteral by means of SPARQL functions

Comment: I am new to sparql. I am using blazegraph for the api (namespace: com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.geoSpatial true) and I am using an .rdf generated by open data. Otherwise I use spring boot and jena (rather I use jena's TBD) for java queries, I use queries directly

Comment: I'm confused. You load the data into what? Jena in-memory or Jena TDB? And why do you use Blazegraph API here if your don't use the Blazegraph triple store? Or do you use the Blazegraph triple store and send queries via Jena Java API?

Comment: but, other than that, your query is wrong as I said. The signature of `geof:distance` is `geometry1, geometry2, unit` - you have to create the gemetry objects from lat/long coordinates in your case. Unfortunately, they "forgot" those constructor function in version 1.0, the next GeoSPARQL will cover those functions. It's rather annoying otherwise

Comment: Optional { ?geo schema:longitude ?lon; schema:latitude ?lat; "Point(?lon ?lat)"^^geo:wktLiteral . } 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openrdf.query.MalformedQueryException: Encountered "  "\"Point(?lon ?lat)\" "" at line 30, column 76.

Comment: yeah, that's invalid syntax. The line is `BIND (STRDT(CONCAT("POINT(",str(?lon), " ", str(?lat), ")"),geo:wktLiteral) as ?wkt) ` to bind it to a variable called `?wkt`. Indeed, for your fixed point you can just write it as literal, i.e. `BIND (geof:distance(?wkt, "POINT (10.0198943 48.4332423)"^^geo:wktLiteral, uom:metre) as ?xr)`

Comment: I load the .rdf from the open data, then I generate the TBD with Jena. Then I prefer to use sparql queries via sql methods (https://jena.apache.org/documentation/jdbc/). blazegraph is to make my requests then place them in my spring boot DAOs

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of Blazegraph API. Jena has a Java API to run queries directly. Also, by default there is no GeoSPARQL support in TDB, see the docs how to enable it: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/geosparql/

Comment: 2021-05-20 20:34:44.116  WARN 16348 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] org.apache.jena.arq.exec                 : URI <http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/distance> has no registered function factory
java.sql.SQLException: The given column does not exist in the result set
 at org.apache.jena.jdbc.results.SelectResults.getNode(SelectResults.java:132)
 at org.apache.jena.jdbc.results.JenaResultSet.getString(JenaResultSet.java:444)

Comment: I used blazegraph because it was the open data manager that advised me (afterwards I just use it to test / improve my requests); maybe i'm working with it the wrong way

Comment: PREFIX geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
PREFIX geof: <http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/>
PREFIX uom: <http://www.opengis.net/def/uom/OGC/1.0/> (...)  BIND (STRDT(CONCAT("POINT(",str(?lon), " ", str(?lat), ")"),geo:wktLiteral) as ?wkt)
BIND (geof:distance(?wkt, "POINT (10.0198943 48.4332423)"^^geo:wktLiteral, uom:metre) as ?xrd)

Comment: and I have this error -> 2021-05-20 20:34:44.116  WARN 16348 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] org.apache.jena.arq.exec                 : URI <http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/distance> has no registered function factory
java.sql.SQLException: The given column does not exist in the result set
 at org.apache.jena.jdbc.results.SelectResults.getNode(SelectResults.java:132)

Comment: Well listen, sincerely thank you for your help, it's been 2 weeks that I have been blocked and I have just posted my calculated distances !!! thank you very much sincerely !!

Comment: ok, yeah - so you enabled GeoSPARQL support in Jena, right? Because this will register the functions and creates a spatial index (for performance). Maybe you can post your solution here as an answer, might help others as well

Comment: I added in maven: <dependency>
            <groupId> org.apache.jena </groupId>
            <artifactId> jena-geosparql </artifactId>
            <version> 4.0.0 </version>
        </dependency> and GeoSPARQLConfig.setupMemoryIndex(); and I also had a version problem (4.0.0 for geosparql and 3.17.0 for jena) I had to put the same version. However, I did not manage to activate fuseki (for the API)

Comment: is it normal that the request lasts more than 2 seconds with the geo distance? I calculate the distance to everything then I use a filter?